# Characteristic function of the sum of two Uniform independent RVs - convolution theorem does not seem to work! Why?

Tags: probability, convolution, uniform-distribution, characteristic-functions

I just came to find this annoying case I do not seem to able to figure out.
Let's assume $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are $Uniform (-m_{j},m_{j})$, $j = 1,2$ and independent; since they are independent the characteristic function of their sum should be equal to the product of their characteristic functions.

In other words let's consider  $X = X_{1} + X_{2}$, then $\phi_{X}(t) = \phi_{X_{1}}(t) \phi_{X_{2}}(t)$.

The characteristic function is easily calculated: $\phi_{X_{j}}(t) = \frac{\sin(t\ m_{j})}{t\ m_{j}}$, right?

So it should also be $\phi_{X}(t) = \frac{\sin(t\ m_{1})}{t\ m_{1}} \frac{\sin(t\ m_{2})}{t \ m_{2}}$; however this is wrong!

If one calculates the convolution of the two PDFs gets $f_{X}(x) = \frac{1}{\Sigma}\left(1-\frac{|x|}{\Sigma}\right)$ (triangular distribution) where $\Sigma = m_{1} + m_{2}$.

Applying the definition of characteristic function to the PDF of $X$ one gets: $\phi_{X}(t) = 2 \frac{1\ - \cos\left(t \Sigma\right)}{\Sigma^2 t^2}$ (after many simplifications) which is the correct one!

What am I doing wrong when multiplying the two individual characteristic functions? I must be applying the convolution theorem (for Fourier transforms, or more accurately, for characteristic functions) wrongly, but I cannot pinpoint what hypotesis is violated... Can somebody help please?

Comment: Who is claiming the wrongness/rightness of the statements here?

Comment: @Snoop Hello, I am new here, this is my first question/post here. I ma claiming the wrongness/rightness here... The wrongness comes from the fact that the Variance calculated from the product of the characteristic functions is not correct, the rightness comes from numerical evaluation of the characteristic function from the PDF of the sum of the two RVs. Perhaps I should have stated this in my question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $X\sim \textrm{Uniform}[-m,m]$ we have
$$E[e^{i\xi X}]=\frac{1}{2m}\int_{-m}^me^{i\xi x}dx=\frac{1}{2m}\frac{e^{i\xi m}-e^{-i\xi m}}{i\xi}=\frac{\sin(m\xi)}{m\xi}$$
So if $X_1,X_2$ are independent and uniform as above with parameters $m_1,m_2>0$:
$$E[e^{i\xi(X_1+X_2)}]=E[e^{i\xi X_1}]E[e^{i\xi X_2}]=\frac{\sin(m_1\xi)\sin(m_2\xi)}{\xi^2 m_1m_2}$$
Now note:
$$\mathbf{1}_{[-m_2,m_2]}(z-x)=\begin{cases}
1&-m_2\leq z-x\leq m_2\\
0&\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}=\begin{cases}
1&m_2+z\geq x\geq z-m_2\\
0&\textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
If we convolve the densities we get for $z \in [-m_1-m_2,m_1+m_2]$
$$\begin{aligned}f_{X_1+X_2}(z)&=\frac{1}{4m_1m_2}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbf{1}_{[-m_1,m_1]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[-m_2,m_2]}(z-x)dx=\\
&=\frac{1}{4m_1m_2}\int_\mathbb{R}\mathbf{1}_{[-m_1,m_1]}(x)\mathbf{1}_{[z-m_2,z+m_2]}(x)dx=\\
&=\frac{1}{4m_1m_2}(\min(z+m_2,m_1)-\max(-m_1,z-m_2))\end{aligned}$$
and $f_{X_1+X_2}(z)=0,\,\forall z \notin [-m_1-m_2,m_1+m_2]$. Example with $(m_1,m_2)=(2,3)$ with numerical Fourier transform of the pdf:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! I now see my mistake! The convolution of two independent uniform RVs is not triangular unless they are i.id. in which case the two expressions of the characteristic functions are equivalent! I started from a stupid assumption!

Comment: Good :) please do accept the answer if you think it resolves the problem!